# Laravel foreach total amount of all products of carts

Tags: laravel

I am creating carts in laravel. I want to display sum of all grandtotal as total but in total only last grandtotal is taken, is it incorrect logic?? i need help to getting total of all grandtotal.. is it any correction in code?? why $total takes only last grandtotal from database..

```
<div class="ps-cart-listing cart_page_empty">
    <table class="table ps-cart__table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Products</th>
          <th>Products Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>GrandTotal</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($items as $item)
        @php $subtotal="0" @endphp
        <tr class="cartpage">
          <td><a class="ps-product__preview" href="{{ route('productDetail',strtolower($item->product_slug))}}"><img class="mr-15" src="{{env('IMAGE_URL')}}/images/{{$item->product_single_image}}" alt="" height="100" width="100"></a></td>
          <td><a href="{{ route('productDetail',strtolower($item->product_slug))}}">{{$item->product_name}}</a></td>
          <td>{{$item->product_price}}</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group--number quantity" id="{{$item->cart_id}}">
              <button class="quantity_minus"><span>-</span></button>
              <input class="form-control cart_id" type="hidden" value="{{$item->cart_id}}">
              <input class="form-control qty_input" type="text" value="{{$item->quantity}}">
              <button class="quantity_plus"><span>+</span></button>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>{{$item->sub_total}}</td>
          @php $subtotal = $subtotal + $item->sub_total @endphp
          <td>
            <div class="ps-remove"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="ps-cart__actions">
      <div class="ps-cart__promotion">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="ps-form--icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Promo Code">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="ps-btn ps-btn--gray">Continue Shopping</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ps-cart__total">
        <h3>Sub Total:<span>{{$subtotal}} Rs.</span></h3>
        <h3>Grand Total:<span>{{$subtotal}}  Rs.</span></h3><a class="ps-btn" href="">checkout<i class="ps-icon-next"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: At start of your foreach item you reset subtotal to 0, move `@php $subtotal="0" @endphp` before foreach

Comment: @Saromase it works thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `$subtotal = 0;` before the loop, otherwise on each loop it will count from `0` :

```
@php 
  $subtotal = 0; 
@endphp

@foreach($items as $item)
  @php
     $subtotal = $subtotal + $item->sub_total
  @endphp
  // 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not manipulating the values of $item->sub_total in the blade view, you can use the `sum()` collection method to get the grand total summing up all the `sub_total` values

No need to declare a $subtotal variable in the blade view and add the $item->sub_total individually to the $subtotal value.

```php
$grandTotal = $items->sum('sub_total');
```

```
<div class="ps-cart__total">
    <h3>Sub Total:<span>{{$subtotal}} Rs.</span></h3>
    <h3>Grand Total:<span>{{$items->sum('sub_total')}}  Rs.</span></h3><a class="ps-btn" href="">checkout<i class="ps-icon-next"></i></a>
</div>
```